# Java interface nested in class

Tags: java, class, interface, tree

So I'm still pretty new to object oriented programming and I was trying to learn more about abstract classes and interfaces in Java. While poking around online I found some code that traverses a tree:

```
import java.util.*;

public class TreeTraverser 
{
    // Please do not change this interface
    public static interface Node 
    {
        int getValue();
        List<Node> getChildren();
    }

    public static List<Node> traverseTreeInWidth(Node root) 
    {
        /*
          Please implement this method to
          traverse the tree in width and return a list of all passed nodes.

          The list should start with the root node, next
          it should contain all second-level nodes, then third-level nodes etc.

          The method shall work optimally with large trees.
         */

        List<Node> passedNodes = new ArrayList<Node>();
        passedNodes.add(root);

        for (int i=0; i<passedNodes.size(); i++)
        {  
            for (Node child: passedNodes.get(i).getChildren())
                passedNodes.add(child);
        }

        return passedNodes;
    }
}
```

My first question has do do with the interface. I thought that interfaces usually have their own files, what would be the purpose/benefit of including it in a class like this?

My second question is how would I be able to access this code and test it with my own tree? I know that if I have another class I would need something like:

```
public class Test implements TreeTraverser.Node {...}
```

But if I try to create my own Node class and then override the methods in the interface I get an error that my return type for public List getChildren() is incompatible, so I'm not sure how to go about testing my own tree.

Thank you ahead of time for trying to help me out.

Comment: The benefit of including an `interface` inside a class, is just so that you can refer to it as `TreeTraverser.Node`, to distinguish it from other `Node` interfaces you may have in other places, and to emphasize that the definition of `Node` is tied to how `TreeTraverser` is supposed to work, for readability.  AND: You should be able to write a `Test` class the way you've said; if it's giving you an error, you did something wrong.  Please post the `Test` class you tried.

Comment: When you implemented it, did you make the return type `List<TreeTraverser.Node>`?  That should work.  `List<Node>` won't, because `Node` isn't visible without the outer class name.

Comment: This is a solution to a betterprogrammer.com puzzle, as far as I can tell

Answer (score 0):

A class that implements `TreeTraverser.Node` should look something like this, with other methods and constructors and other members added as needed:

```
public class Test implements TreeTraverser.Node {

    public int getValue() { ... }

    public List<TreeTraverser.Node> getChildren() { ... }
    // note that the name Node has to be qualified

}
```

Comment: This is about as far as I got, could you elaborate on what you mean that the name Node has to be qualified? The way I had it was a nested class in Test but that's when I had the error.

Comment: Changing the return type to List<TreeTraverser.Node> did solve the error. So my next question is when I have a class for Node how do I use it as a TreeTraverser.Node or how would I manipulate a TreeTraverser.Node?

Comment: @user2821731 What I mean by "qualified" (I hope this is the right term): If a name is defined inside a class, you can't use the name outside that class without qualifying it by putting `ClassName.` in front of the name, or by putting `<object>.` or `<expression>.` to denote an object of the class that owns it.  This is just the compiler's rules about what names are visible to whom and where.  `import static` can be used to make some names visible without needing a qualifier.  But I don't use it much so I don't know the rules for it off the top of my head.